# C++ compiler error base class issue

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm getting this->

> error -type ‘Ship’ is not a direct base of ‘CruiseShip’-

I cannot figure it out. This is where the error is occurring I am assuming. I am not really sure I guess how I should be calling the base class?

> CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string n, string y, int p) : Ship(n,y)

**CruiseShip.cpp**

```
#include "CruiseShip.h"
#include "Ship.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Ship s;
  CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string n, string y, int p) : Ship(n,y)
  {
    passengers=p;
  }
  //A print function that overrides the print function in the base class.
  //The CruiseShip class's print function should display only the ship's
  //name and the maximum number of passengers.
   void print()
   {
    cout<<"Name: "<<s.getName()<<"\nMaximum passengers:"<<passengers<<endl;
  cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
   }
```

**CruiseShip.h**

```
#ifndef CRUISESHIP_H
#define CRUISESHIP_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Ship;

class CruiseShip{
    private:
        int passengers;
        Ship::Ship s;
    public:
    CruiseShip(string, string, int);
    virtual void print();
};

#endif
```

**Ship.cpp**

```
#include "Ship.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string name;
string built;

Ship::Ship(){

}
Ship::Ship(string n, string b)
{
   name = n;
  built = b;

}
//accessors and mutators methods
string getName()
{
  return name;
}
string getBuilt()
{
  return built;
}
//A virtual print function that displays
//the ship's name and the year it was built
void print()
{
  cout<<"Name:"<<getName()<<"\nYear built:"<<getBuilt()<<endl;
  cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
}
```

**Ship.h**

```
#ifndef SHIP_H
#define SHIP_H
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

class Ship{
private:
    string name;
    string built;

public:
    Ship();
    Ship(string, string);
    string getName();
    string getBuilt();
    virtual void print();


};
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to derive CruiseShip from Ship:

```
class CruiseShip : public Ship {
```

this:

```
CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string n, string y, int p) : Ship(n,y)
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is a base class constructor call, but you have not derived CruiseShip from Ship, yet compiler knows that Ship is a class type.

Comment: So once I change this _CruiseShip::Ship(string n, string y, int p) : Ship(n,y)_. Do I need to change the constructor in the header file?

Comment: You only need to derive from `Ship`, so adding `: public Ship` will suffice. You also probably dont need this `Ship::Ship s;`

Comment: You might also need to `#include "Ship.h"` in your cruiseship header